# Angular 13 + NestJS File Upload

Tags: javascript, angular, http, nestjs

I have the following API in my NestJS controller:

```js
import 'multer';
import csv from 'csvtojson';

import { Body, Controller, HttpStatus, Post, Res, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Express, Response } from 'express';

@Controller()
export class TestController {
  @Post('/test-upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async bulkUpload(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Body() body: any, @Res() response: Response) {
    try {
      const csvString = file.buffer.toString();
      const jsonArray = await csv().fromString(csvString);
      const id = body['id'];

      console.log(id);

      // Send back the results
      response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(jsonArray);
    } catch (e) {
      response.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

In my Angular code, I call it like this:

```js
bulkUpload(event: any): Observable<any> {
  const url = '/test-upload';

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
  formData.append('id', 4);

  const options = { reportProgress: true, responseType: 'json' };

  this.http.post<any>(url, formData, options).subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => console.log(data),
    error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
  });
}
```

I'm uploading the following CSV file:

```
id,name,status
2,test,active
5,foo,inactive
9,bar,inactive
```

and this is what the file looks like when I console log it on the Angular side:

```
lastModified: 1660946990280
lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 19 2022 18:09:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
name: "test.csv"
size: 61
type: "text/csv"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

When I call the `bulkUpload` function, I get the following error:

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0"
statusCode: 400
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? When I call the endpoint from Postman, it works fine and I get no errors. Am I missing some headers or something else? How do I upload a non-json file?

Comment: Hard to tell without actually seeing what is posted and received..

Comment: I added the CSV file and a console log of the file in the question. Is there something I should post? It never gets inside the the NestJS API function so I can't show any logs from there.

Comment: If that last one is the actual response, the error makes sense. Not valid Json..?

Comment: How do I tell the Angular code that I'm passing a CSV file? Or a non-json file?

Comment: Maybe responseType: 'text'? Not entirely sure, been a while since I had to parse non-json responses 

Comment: There might be some misunderstanding here. I'm trying to upload a CSV file and send the file over to my NestJS api. I get the "Bad request" error when I make the http request. Also, responseType only takes 'json'. It doesn't accept 'text'.

Comment: Right. So what does the exact request look like? I’d expect something form-encoded like? (Network console)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in that direction! I saw that the 'Content-Type' header was 'application/json'. I changed it to 'multipart/form-data' and it works perfectly now. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make sure the 'Content-Type' header was set to 'multipart/form-data'. I changed the Angular function to the following:

```js
bulkUpload(event: any): Observable<any> {
  const url = '/test-upload';

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
  formData.append('id', 4);

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  headers = headers.append('Accept', '*/*');

  this.http.post<any>(url, formData, { headers }).subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => console.log(data),
    error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
  });
}
```

After that, the error went away and I was able to send the file to my NestJS API correctly.